# c# replace breakline inside two xml tags

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace all the \r \n inside a xml string

I have this regex pattern that do my job:

```
xmlString = " <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"> <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\"> <head> \n\r<meta name="author" \ncontent="John Doe"> </head> </html> "

Regex.Replace(xmlString, @"\r?\n\s*", "");
```

But now i want to use this pattern inside 2 xml tags (head in this case)

```
Regex.Replace(xmlString, @"<head>\r?\n\s*</head>", "");
```

So this expression is trying to replace all the breaklines inside the head tag.. But for some reason it is not working...

i saw some other topics using ?. or *, but not working

Ideas?

Comment: Please note that you should not be "parsing", or editing in your case, HTML with regex, see https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't mind the order of new line and carriage return you can use the following regex with the look ahead and look behind for the head tag:

```
Regex.Replace(xmlString, @"(?<=\<head\>.*)(\n|\r)(?=.*\</head\>)", "", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Comment: thank you. Your solution fixed my problem. I was very far from the answer